How to get notified when a GitHub organisation is archived
Is there a way to be notified via Webhook when the organisation that has installed a GitHub app is archived (and unarchived).
Looking through the documentation life https://docs.github.com/en/webhooks/webhook-events-and-payloads could not see support for such.

No there isn't a specific event. You may be able to track changes to your organization or repositories. For example, if all repositories in an organization become read-only, it may indicate that the organization has been archived. But it is an empirical method
